# Virtual Network using Hyper-V

Tags: domain, hyper-v

I'm having some issues creating a virtual network using hyper-v.  Right now I have PC1 as a Domain controller, it's running the domain D1.  All I did was setup Active Directory Domain Services and created a domain.

It appears that all worked fine, I can add users, there's a domain the main pc (PC1) is on.  The problem comes in when I try to add a virtual machine to the network.  PC2 is also running 2K8R2 and when I go to add to the domain it complains about not being able to find the domain.

I figured this has to do with the DNS, so I overrode the DNS on the adapter to point to PC1 and I was able to add it to the domain.  However, now the PC doesn't get internet.  I'm thinking this is a DHCP issue, but I have no clue how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the DNS server which it is now querying does not have access to the internet and therefore can not resolve internet web pages.

Your easiest solution will be to go to the DNS server of the domain controller and make sure forwarding or root servers are setup so that the domain server can query alternate DNS servers.

Comment: The DNS server's internet is fine.  Works dandy.

Comment: @Dave - ... So, both computers have a physical connection to the internet, but pc1 is resolving DNS queries to D1 and not your ISP, therefore, it cannot resolve internet addresses. You need to go to D1 and enable DNS forwarding in DNS server so it can resolve external addresses, or enable root hints.

Comment: One computer is physical, second is virtual.  The DNS and AD machine is the physical.  The internet works on the physical and the virtual until I join a domain (on the virtual i have to point it to the physical's IP in the network controllers dns setting, is  there a way around this?).  I'm going to try DNS fowarding.

Comment: @Dave:  Every machine in the domain needs to send its DNS queries to the DNS server on your network, and the DNS server needs to forward any unresolved queries (any request not to domain machines) to external DNS servers.  The issue has nothing to do with virtualisation at all.

Comment: @dave - as I and Jason404 said, if this is a problem after changing DNS server, it is clear that the DNS server is not forwarding unresolved queries.

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I setup Hyper-V internet access to my virtual machines](https://serverfault.com/questions/21949/how-do-i-setup-hyper-v-internet-access-to-my-virtual-machines)

> In Virtual Network Manager on the
>   hyper V box, select the physical NIC
>   that you're using in the properties
>   for each VM's network connection. The
>   connection type will need to be set to
>   "External" to allow the VMs access to
>   the network as if they were
>   "physically" plugged in.
>
> At that point you can treat them as
>   directly attached.
>
> Also make sure `Allow management
>   operating systems to share this
>   network adapter` is ticked if in a
>   single NIC environment.

Another useful source is [Accentient - Virtual Networking in Hyper-V](http://blog.accentient.com/VirtualNetworkingInHyperV.aspx).

Comment: This appears to be a DNS issue, which the OP can easily check by trying to reach a website using an IP address rather than a domain address.  eg. 209.85.231.104

Answer (score 0):

**You need a DNS server on your network**.  I usually add the **DNS role** to the same (VM) server that runs ADDS.  You then have to **[set the DNS server to forward queries not resolved in the local cache to upstream DNS servers on the internet](http://networkadminkb.com/kb/Knowledge%20Base/DNS/How%20to%20configure%20an%20Active%20Directory%20Integrated%20Conditional%20DNS%20Forwarder.aspx)**.

Comment: The DNS server is said to be working well.

Comment: @harrymc: He said that DNS is working for internal requests, but the domain members do not have internet access once they are sending DNS requests to the internal DNS server.  This is exactly what would happen when the DNS server is not forwarding unresolved requests to an external internet DNS server.